# Which Wiki System supports searching by criteria?

Tags: web, content-management-system, mediawiki, wiki

My Question is best explained using an example:
Please visit this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_linux
Say I wanted to set up a wiki with similar sites where you could search by the criteria seen on the right.
For example: There is a search inteface on that wiki with a drop-down menu called license and one called OS Family, and you would make your choice and it would then deliver all OS Sites matching your search.
I hope my question can be understood.
Which wiki software supports that? Mybe with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/) and [SemanticFormsSelect](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemanticFormsSelect).